# Regex ou Replace em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Como faço uma alteração de string, adicionando novo conteudo?

Exemplo:

```
<div><span id="number">1195555666<span><div>

<script>var newNumber = $(#number).replace('(11)95555-6666')</script>
console.log(newNumber);
```

porem o numero é uma variavel, então o replace não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituindo o `<span>` por `<input>` e usando o plugin `Jquery.Mask` vc consegue:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="1195555666">
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#number').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
</script>
```

> [Referência do **Jquery.Mask**](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Tem 3 erros no seu script:

1. `$(#number)` falta aspas em `#number`
2. `$(...)` retorna um OBJETO jQuery, logo não existe o método `.replace`, este método pertence ao `String.prototype` (nativo do JavaScript)
3. As tags de fechamento estão erradas:

   ```
   <div><span id="number">1195555666<span><div>
   ```

   Deveria ser:

   ```
   <div><span id="number">1195555666</span></div>
   ```

O correto deveria ser provavelmente usar `text` ou `html` que são métodos do jQuery, assim:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span id="number">1195555666</span></div>
    
<script>$('#number').text('(11)95555-6666')</script>
```

Se pretende pegar o valor no `console.log` faça assim:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span id="number">1195555666</span></div>
    
<script>
var antigo = $('#number').text(); //Pega valor antigo

$('#number').text('(11)95555-6666'); //Seta valor novo

var novo = $('#number').text(); //Pega valor novo

console.log(antigo);
console.log(novo);
</script>
```